# Using a LASSO model on one dataset to predict values in another - in R

Tags: r, lasso

I have two datasets. One is called "house_data_one" and the other is called "house_data_two." Both datasets have essentially the same columns, but the second has different observations from the first in it. The only difference between them (other than the actual observations) is that "house_data_one" has a column called "sale_price" and "house_data_two" doesn't.

This becomes important because I'm trying to create a (LASSO) model of the "sale_price" variable in the "house_data_one" dataset and use that model to predict the "sale_price" observations in "house_data_two." To do this, I've tried to use the glmnet() function and make "house_data_one" my training dataset and "house_data_two" my test dataset. But one of the inputs to the glmnet() function is model.matrix(), which is fine for the first dataset because I can write something like this

```
train = house_data_one
x_train = model.matrix(sale_price~., train)[,-1]
```

but this doesn't work for the second dataset because there is no variable "sale_price" in the second dataset to operate the function on.

```
test = house_data_two
x_test = model.matrix(sale_price~., test)[,-1] #This won't run
```

So my question is, can someone help me either restructure this regression, or provide some demonstration for how to rework the code in a way that will run?

More of my code is below for reference:

```
set.seed(1)
train = training_data
test = test_one_data
test_one_data$sale_price <- predict(lasso_mod, training_data)

x_train = model.matrix(sale_price~., train)[,-1]
x_test = model.matrix(sale_price~., test)[,-1]

y_train = train %>%
  select(sale_price) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  as.numeric()

y_test = test %>%
  select(sale_price) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  as.numeric()
```

```
grid = 10^seq(10, -2, length = 100)
lasso_mod = glmnet(x_train, 
                   y_train, 
                   alpha = 1, 
                   lambda = grid)
plot(lasso_mod)
```

```
set.seed(1)
cv.out = cv.glmnet(x_train, y_train, alpha = 1) # Fit lasso model on training data
plot(cv.out) # Draw plot of training MSE as a function of lambda
bestlam = cv.out$lambda.min # Select lamda that minimizes training MSE
lasso_pred = predict(lasso_mod, s = bestlam, newx = x_test) # Use best lambda to predict test data
mean((lasso_pred - y_test)^2) # Calculate test MSE
```

```
out = glmnet(x, y, alpha = 1, lambda = grid) # Fit lasso model on full dataset
lasso_coef = predict(out, type = "coefficients", s = bestlam)[1:74,] # Display coefficients using lambda chosen by CV
lasso_coef
```

Also, I've heard that it's often good to put some of the data in these questions but I tried to  use the dput() function to take the first ten lines of the data and the script when on for many, many lines - there are 74 columns in the dataset. I've put a photo of a subset of the data below for reference anyway, which I hope will be be helpful.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to predict the sales price of the second data set? If so, use `predict(model, newdata = seconddataset)`, not `model.matrix`. I also think you misunderstand the purpose of a test set: It must be labeled also, or otherwise you have no means of expressing the performance on the test set. If you want a test set, you should divide your first data set into train/test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Frans Rodenburg commented, most packages have a `predict()` function that takes a model and a new data set and returns a set of predictions on the new data set.

If for some reason you have to provide a model matrix in your application, note that the model matrix is a function only of the predictor values, not the outcome values. In R, you can ask for the model matrix with a formula that omits the outcome. (Such formulas are used for things like density plots.) If your `test` data frame has all the predictors but lacks the outcome, you should be able to write `x_test = model.matrix(~., test)[,-1]` (if you need to omit the column for the intercept).